# Symfony 2 + Assetic Runtime Java Error

Tags: symfony, yui-compressor

I'm trying to set my Symfony 2 project to combine and compress a number of javascript files. Below is an example of the tag I'm using to accomplish this:

```
{% javascripts 'bundles/acmedemo/js/*' output='js/plugins.js' filter='closure' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I've config to map to the yui compressor jar.

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        closure:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar
```

When I try to bring up the page in the browser it takes a while to load and doesn't include the output file. I tried to run the app/console assetic:dump command and got this error:

[RuntimeException]
If no input file is specified, it defaults to stdin. In this case, the 'type' option is required. Otherwise, the 'type' option is required only if the input. And the windows prompt cuts it off.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you yuicompressor file actually located in `%kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar` ? not `%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar` ?

Check this link, maybe something will help http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/dde8b418813bab37/1d4e42a7396f2e0f?lnk=gst&q=yui

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly: the path has to be put in: ""
The config will look like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        closure:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't an error as such but you seem to be configuring the YUI compressor from Yahoo as 'closure'. Google Closure is a different JS compression tool.